# Convert a GCP Dataflow Successful Job into Pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl, google-cloud-dataflow

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I have run few DataFlow jobs (MongoDB to BigQuery) and they successfully completed with the desired data loaded on BigQuery.

However, when I try to transform them into recurring jobs (aka GCP Dataflow Pipelines), the job does not complete and here is the error log message I get:

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
"jobName":"projects/<project-name>/locations/us-central1/jobs/datapipelines-<pipeline-name>", 
"status":"NOT_FOUND", 
"targetType":"HTTP",
"url":"https://datapipelines.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project-name>/locations/us-central1/pipelines/<pipeline-name>:run"}
```

Did anyone else encounter the same issue? Any recommendations?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you configure your recurring Dataflow pipelines please ?

Comment: I selected the successful job and clicked 'Import as Pipeline' and then I only had to define the frequency of the batch job (hourly at minute 0).

Answer (score 1):

Importing as a pipeline should work as expected. Did this workflow work before for any other pipeline? It might be due to Cloud Scheduler or Data Pipelines API not being enabled on the project as it looks like from the error that the pipeline did not get created successfully.

Comment: Dataflow Jobs work successfully but no Dataflow Pipeline was able to run. 

Cloud Scheduler API and Data Pipelines API are enabled and I have also granted the role permissions to Cloud Scheduler service account.

Comment: Ok, if you can't create any data pipeline, then it mostly looks something is misconfigured in the project/API. Would it possible for you to create a support issue? This would allow us to better debug and fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Manav. I do appreciate your help. Unfortunately, when I try to file a support ticket, I get "This organization isn't eligible to file tech-related support cases. To do so, we invite you to upgrade your service package." Is there any other way to report this bug? Thanks!